# How sound waves travel through a barrier?

Tags: acoustics

[image]How sound waves travel through a barrier?
Sound wave is result of compression and rarefraction of gases. This pressure difference make the air molecules to oscillate. [Fig 1]

When sound wave hit the plane wall it reflect. I am considering the same thing for the pressure difference. But when the wave hits the barriers like as shown in below image. How will be the pressure distribution? Will it follow the same compression and refraction pattern? Or it will be a high pressure region at corner? [fig 2]

Answer (score 2):

Although sound is a longitudinal wave, the behaviour is very similar to a transverse wave; so you can just think about what would happen if your question was about ripples on the surface of water.

So, I think your diagram shows a plain wavefront hitting a barrier with a small gap in it; and I think that you are asking what the wave pattern would be like on the other side.

The answer is that if the gap in the barrier is small compared to the wavelength, then on the other side of barrier the waves will spread out in a circular pattern centred on the gap.

A bit like this image from the Wikipedia page on the Huygens-Fresnel principle:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I wanted to know-how will be the pressure distribution at the left side of the barrier. Any book, study which can help me to understand this?

Comment: Apologies for my misunderstanding (in that case the title of your question is a bit misleading). Are the thin horizontal lines in your diagram also barriers?

Comment: @mech_duck what would happen on the lefthand side in (for example) the animated image above, is that  most of the plane wave would be reflected back from the barrier. This reflected wave, travelling from right to left, would interfere with the incoming wave to produce a *standing wave* on the left of the barrier - i.e. a region where there is a pattern of bands of compression and rarefaction that oscillate in time but do not appear to move. Note that this effect is not shown in the image! In the case of your diagram, the pattern would be more complex because your barriers are angled.